# "Invalid Postback" exception on custom GridView with custom row events

Tags: c#, javascript, exception, gridview

I think I have figured out what happens with this program.

This is part of the markup.

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upGrid" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="dgvPeliculas" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
                    CssClass="mGrid" EmptyDataText="No hay más películas" OnPageIndexChanging="dgvPeliculas_PageIndexChanging1"
                    EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="true" OnRowDataBound="dgvPeliculas_RowDataBound">
                </asp:GridView>                
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <table class="LogIn">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAlquiler" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAlquilar" runat="server" Text="Alquilar" CssClass="AdminButtons"
                                        OnClick="btnAlquilar_Click" OnClientClick="javascript: Click_Alquilar(); return false" />
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnNuevo" runat="server" Text="Nuevo" CssClass="AdminButtons" OnClick="btnNuevo_Click"
                                OnClientClick="javascript: Click_Nuevo(); return false" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnEditar" runat="server" Text="Editar" CssClass="AdminButtons" OnClick="btnEditar_Click"
                                OnClientClick="javascript: Click_Editar(); return false" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnBorrar" runat="server" Text="Borrar" OnClientClick="javascript: Click_Borrar(); return false"
                                CssClass="AdminButtons" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

I have coded it in such a way that the buttons modify it when a row is selected. The rows are selected by changing the "onclick" event (changed during the RowDataBound function), and a Javascript function.

This is how I change the code behind:

```
protected void dgvPeliculas_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            dgvPeliculas.CssClass = "mGrid";
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string rowID = String.Empty;
                rowID = "row" + e.Row.RowIndex;
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("id", rowID);
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "onClick(" + "'" + rowID + "'" + ")");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='pointer'; this.style.backgroundColor = '#B0C5BB';");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor = '';");
            }
        }
```

This is the JavaScript function:

/

```
 function onClick(rowID)
     {
         //Si no hay ninguna seleccionada
         if (selected == '') {
             index = rowID;
             selected = document.getElementById(rowID);
             selected.onmouseover = '';
             selected.onmouseout = '';
             selected.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
         }
         else {
             //Si se deselecciona
             if (selected == document.getElementById(rowID)) {
                 selected.onmouseover = onmouseover;
                 selected.onmouseout = onmouseout;
                 selected.style.backgroundColor = '';
                 selected = '';
                 index = '';
             }
             //Deseleccionar el actual y seleccionar el nuevo
             else {
                 selected.onmouseover = onmouseover;
                 selected.onmouseout = onmouseout;
                 selected.style.backgroundColor = '';

                 index = rowID;
                 selected = document.getElementById(rowID);
                 selected.onmouseover = '';
                 selected.onmouseout = '';
                 selected.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
             }
         }
     }
```

The New button shows a ModalPopupExtender, and from there it calls a JavaScript function to validate its contents, and then does a postback to code behind to check and update the database. It also appends the register on the Grid, obviously.

The Edit button and the rest through the exception. The Edit function is particular, because its functionality is similar to that of the New button. It shows the ModalPopupExtender, goes to the JavaScript function, does the postback, to the database and updates. But this one needs to have one of the rows in the Grid selected (otherwise, there's nothing to be edited). I believe this is the reason why it throws the "Invalid Postback or Callback" exception. The same condition applies to the other buttons, and all of them throw the same exception. All, except New, which doesn't need to have a row selected.

Do you think this is the reason why I'm having this problem? And if so, how can I fix it?

Sorry if you consider this a repost of one of my previous threads, but I haven't been able to fix the problem, and I think this gives me a new clue that I can't work out neither.

Thanks.